# Customizing Router Firmware

Tags: linux, firmware

i've got a netgear DG834 router, and i want to have a go at hacking the firmware on it to try and add a Wake on Lan option. Netgear let you download the source and the tools to build an image, but i'm not sure where to start.

I've never programmed on a unix platform before, and never done any firmware hacking, just wondering if anyone knows any good resources i can look through

Ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for openwrt or tomato or some other firmware.

Comment: i dont think they will run on the v5 router i have. I'd like to have a go at it even if there is a custom one already

Answer (score 0):

Well, hacking would be fine... except that wake-on-lan requires hardware support, which almost certainly does not exist in your device.

Comment: sorry my question might not have explained that very well, i dont want to wake the router up, i want to use the router to wake up other devices

Comment: Ah... yeah, that's definitely doable, if you can get a Linux built for the device in the first place.